# Unit testing with core data in objective c

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, core-data

My coredata methods are here.  How to write unit test case to check this.

Method to save to coredata

```
- (void)saveUserDetails:(Model *)userDetail {
if(userDetail != nil) {
    UserEntity *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“EntityName” inManagedObjectContext:[self sharedContext]];

    NSArray *fetchArray = [self fetchUserWithUsername:userDetail.username];

    if ([fetchArray count] == 0) {
        user.username = userDetail.username;
        [self saveContext];
    }
}
}
```

Method to fetch from coredata

```
- (NSArray *)fetchUserWithUsername:(NSString *)username {
if (username != nil) {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *userEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“EntityName” inManagedObjectContext:[self sharedContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:userEntity];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username = %@", username];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self sharedContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return fetchedObjects;
}

return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an in-memory store and inject this into your object.

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyResource" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
XCTAssertTrue([psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL] ? YES : NO, @"Should be able to add in-memory store");

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
```

Comment: I've added this code at the end to the above code

UserDetails *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    
    user.username = @"XXX";

And the test case is succeeded but how we get to know the save method will work

Comment: I guess this won't make any changes with the real database. Am I right?

Comment: It *does* make changes. Especially fetching is different, because the set of predicates is different: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html and then *Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors*. However, if the restrictions does not apply to your code, you can use an in-memory store. Building up a SQL store at the beginning of the tests is closer to the reality. In many cases you want to have some instances around in the store for testing.

Comment: @Sivagami it will make no changes to your real database, it is not even accessed at all.